# How do "Crabs" make money exactly?

Tags: options, option-strategies

So again i'm used to Crypto Currencies, and since im stupid i learn most things from threads from /biz/ (fortunately i still take decisions based on myself), i've seen plenty on lingo like a bull means a person who bought shares and is intending to sell them at a higher price or someone who has a long option(or a call), a bear is someone who borrowed someones shares sold them immediately and is intending to buy them back again for a lower price receiving the difference meaning a short(or a put).

***But how does one make money from the market not fluctuating a lot, or ending up in the same value as bought assuming this is what they refer by "crab market".*** Is it buying at a certain low point and then selling at a high point and repeating it multiple times and if so how can this be done automatically without constantly setting new lines?
what if the stock literally doesn't fluctuate: ie there's no offers on the stock and theres no transactions or trading

Comment: Your question is largely meaningless.   If you're asking "are there some markets or instruments where it is very unlikely to make money by trading" the answer is extremely simple, "sure".

Comment: @Fattie im asking this because i can't find anything by searching "crab" only find bulish patterns and other nonsense but it appears to be an option just like puts and calls i just dont know the name

Comment: YES @Flux thank you!

Comment: unrelatedly @Imeguras , I have a bad feeling that you think you can trade markets and win.  If I am correct, my advice is always, immediately take ten thousand bucks and try your hand.  This will "get it out of your system."

Comment: @Fattie nope, i apreciate your consern but im just interested in how it all works i've always been interested in stocks but its all so bureocratic to get one that i prefer cripto(it gives me a certain pleasure going to my wallet/node) and seeing that i have half a monero coin
Of course you may be wondering, how much did i put on it. I only placed what i was willing to lose in fact i kinda laugh when it deteriorates in value because as soon as i placed the money i knew i might've just burned it
Coincidentely i've been having luck since even on the bear market i doubled my "investments"/gamble

Comment: Does "/biz/" refer to https://www.reddit.com/r/biz/?

Comment: @Imeguras The answer to "how it all works" is sometimes "it doesn't work the way you think it does".

Comment: @Flux I think they mean https://boards.4channel.org/biz/ 

Comment: @Cody yes you are right! im into losing money professionaly